# Can I capture the result of the continuation passed to Printf.ksprintf?

Tags: .net, f#

I am trying to do something like:

```
let execute command =
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (command)
    sprintf "%s (command output!)" command

let shell fmt = Printf.ksprintf execute fmt

printfn "%s" (shell "ls -a %s" "/Users/david")
```

Where the intended output would be:

```
ls -a /Users/david (command output!)
```

But I can't see any way for the result type of `execute` to "escape" `ksprintf`. Is there any way for me to capture the output of `execute`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to capture the output of the process - by default it just uses the same terminal as the containing app.  Something like (taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx)

```
let execute command =
    let p = new System.Diagnostics.Process(command)
    p.UseShellExecute <- false;
    p.RedirectStandardOutput<-true //you might want to do stderr as well
    p.Start()
    let output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    p.WaitForExit()
    sprintf "%s %s" command output
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific – I know how to capture the output, but how do I _return_ this string from the body of the function passed to `ksprintf`? I want the caller of `shell` in my example to receive the output, not merely have it printed out in the execution function.

Comment: @DavidSiegel - just add `output` on its own line after the `sprintf`

Comment: Then the program doesn't typecheck. You're only looking at the definition of `execute`. Placing `output` on the next line changes the return type of `execute` and then I cannot define `shell.`